# Problem with "in" operator in mongoose 6.2?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get all the products with the ids in the array, however when I execute this portion of code there are no results obtained, I checked the DB and the products exists. The next is basically the query

```
const productsIds= ['62b30ffd17c3f70fe7faef8a','62b30ffd17c3f70fe7faef8a','62b30ffd17c3f70fe7faefa5'];
const dbProducts = await Product.find({ _id:{ $in:productsIds} });
```

Is somethig wrong?
The result of that query is an empty array

Comment: One of the common errors is that your `_id` is ObjectId while your `productsIds` array are strings. Make sure they share the same type when you are doing a query.

Comment: I have reviewed the use of strings and objectIds and it is correct, with the "in" operator you can send an array of strings to perform the query, I restarted the server and everything worked correctly without having made any changes, perhaps there was a problem in the backend with the connection to the DB although it is strange  because everything else was working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Literally I solved this problem reRunning the server and with no code changes